# Use of вроде in questions

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление

I don't understand what вроде adds to this question. Can someone translate or paraphrase it for me?

> ты вроде говорил, что встречал её?

Comment: вроде should be separated by commas from left and right

Comment: @Anixx: We say "set off by commas"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This adds meaning of "not completely sure" to the **declarative** sentence.
In the other words: *I'm almost sure, but not completely sure*.

So the translation is

> I thought, you told me that you met her. Am I right?

In opposite, without `вроде`, this phrase becomes the following question:

> Have you ever told me, that you met her?

Comment: Thank you! I've also seen вроде бы used like this - are they interchangeable? If not, what is the difference, if any?

Comment: I believe that they are equal in such sentences.

Answer (score 4):

@Dmitry is correct for the asked question ( I can't add a comment due to lack of rep ), just wanted to expand on the use of the word 'вроде' ( adding uncertainty/fuzziness ) here's another use:

> Она́ писа́ла что́-то вро́де мемуáров.
>
> She was writing something like (or something that resembled) memorandums.

and

> Ты же вро́де как сдал на права́.
>
> Haven't you passed your driving test?

[source](http://masterrussian.com/vocabulary/vrode_like.htm)

Answer (score 2):

It means "similar to", "like" or "apparently". Much akin to the English word "like" in the teenage contingent of the California Valley, it can be a parasite in speech.

```
ты вроде говорил, что встречал её?
```

Means:

```
Didn't you say that you had met her?
```

or:

```
I believe you had said you had met her, no?
```

Comment: I know the basic meaning of вроде, again, my question was strictly about it's meaning in this and similar statements.

Answer (score 2):

`вроде` in this case is expressing uncertainty:

> ты вроде говорил, что встречал её?
>
> You seem to have said that you have met her.

or

> Haven't you said that you have met her?

If you omit `вроде`, then it is simply a question: "Have you said that you have met her?" With `вроде` the sentence is expressing doubt: "I thought you said that you've met her, but I am not sure".

Comment: Thank you! Is словно the colloquial equivalent of this word? Can it be used the same way?

Comment: Not really... словно is expressing a comparison, without the connotation of doubt. If you use словно, you just get a simile. Also, in this particular usage "вроде" is the colloquial term. A more literary expression would be "кажется" (literally "it seems").